# Wireless data recieving and sending using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wireless

I have 3 different computers in 3 different locations ,and i need to build a software that can control these 3 computers using vb.net,my basic need is to play a video on my server system ,and i need these 3 computers to play the same video at the same time , how can i send and recieve wireless data using vb.net

Comment: Monitor cannot receive wireless data, you need a computer for that.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload the video to any video hosting site and then use this code to send a message to the computers (using there public IP adress where stated):

```
Public Class MessageReciever
Dim Listener As New TcpListener(5534) 'or any unused port
Dim Client As TcpClient

Private Sub MessageReciever_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Listener.Stop()
End Sub
Private Sub MessageReciever_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
    Listener.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim message As String
    Dim nStart As Integer
    Dim nLast As Integer
    If Listener.Pending = True Then
        message = ""
        Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(Client.GetStream())
        While reader.Peek > -1
            message &= Convert.ToChar(reader.Read()).ToString
        End While
        If message.Contains("</>") Then
            nStart = InStr(message, "</>") + 4
            nLast = InStr(message, "<\>")
            message = Mid(message, nStart, nLast - nStart)
        End If
    End If
    If message = "playVideo" then
         Process.start("http://youtube.com/watch?yourvideo") 'opens website in default browser
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Import all the stuff it tells you to.

If you put this software on the computers you would like to play the video on and then put the following code on the main computer you would like to control the others on:

```
Option Explicit On
Public Class MessageSender
Dim client As TcpClient
Private Sub PlayVidButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayVidButton.Click
    Try
        client = New TcpClient(computer ur controllings public ip, 5534) 'you can get your public ip @ portforward.com and make sure the port here is the same as the one entered for the listener in the other form

        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(client.GetStream())
        writer.Write("playVideo")
        writer.Flush()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

I hope this helps your problem.